# Parsing multiple instances of data

Tags: bash, parsing, text, grep, sh

I am trying to parse multiple instances of data from a textfile.  I can grep and grab one line and the lat/lon associated with that find, but I am having issued parsing multiple instances:

```
... CATEGORICAL ...

SLGT   33618675 34608681 35658642 36668567 38218542 41018363
       41588227 41918045 41377903 40177805 38927813 37817869
       36678030 35068154 33368262 33078321 32888462 33618675
SLGT   30440169 31710202 33010185 33730148 34010037 33999962
       33709892 32869871 30979883 29539912 29430025 30440169
SLGT   41788755 41698893 42069059 42639132 43889124 44438960
       44438757 43988717 43278708 42398720 41788755
MRGL   42897922 41907743 40147624 38837627 37637700 35897915
       35028021 34038079 33118130 31998226 31698419 32078601
       32818733 33848809 34758764 36998623 38588677 39458701
       40178757 40608870 41069099 43549479 44499512 44809478
       45259379 44989263 45109100 45718986 46478920 46758853
       46738752 46398664 44768565 44308457 43198218
MRGL   29720174 31900221 33650181 34160154 34430032 34649931
       34159800 32539784 31359767 29739808 29299723 28969581
       28959440 99999999 26769674 26579796 26139874
TSTM   45077438 43177245 40597113 99999999 30488085 30248563
       29588926 28739072 28569092 99999999 27138160 27578139
       27908100 27848061 27518032 26968006 26338005 25698017
       25338025 25088048 25058071 25238109 25578128 25888157
       26218171 26578170 26988163 27138160 99999999 29200399
       31910374 33520340 35190229 35450147 36109944 36399709
       35779395 36399167 38559059 40189373 41729594 43029985
       42820283 42860489 43580863 44121062 44521135 45281179
       46271166 47561286 48251548 48671765 49051814 99999999
       38810245 37660271 37120322 36950398 37090559 37380662
       38090741 39410791 39980777 40930695 41380598 41370510
       41190353 40840299 40220263 38810245
```

From: https://www.spc.noaa.gov/products/outlook/archive/2019/KWNSPTSDY1_201906241300.txt

Here is my code and results:

```
#!/bin/sh

sed -n '/^MRGL/,/^TSTM/p;/^TSTM/q' day1_status | sed '$ d' | sed -e 's/MRGL//g' > MRGL
while read line
do
  count=1
  ncols=$(echo $line | wc -w)
  while [ $count -le $ncols ]
  do
    echo $line | cut -d' ' -f$count
    ((count++))
  done
done < MRGL > MRGL_output.txt


cat  MRGL_output.txt | sed ':a;s/\B[0-9]\{2\}\>/.&/;ta'| sed 's/./, -/6' > MRGL_final
```

---

## Results:

one instance of MRGL and the lat/lon associated with that polygon

```
more MRGL
   32947889 34137855 35307825 36147735 36327622 35797468
   27107968 25518232 99999999 27088303 28418215 30208125
       30618064
```

Turn the line above into a single instance of lines

```
more MRGL_output.txt
32947889
34137855
35307825
36147735
36327622
35797468
27107968
25518232
99999999
27088303
28418215
30208125
30618064
```

Final format that I need it in

```
more MRGL_final
32.94, -78.89
34.13, -78.55
35.30, -78.25
36.14, -77.35
36.32, -76.22
35.79, -74.68
27.10, -79.68
25.51, -82.32
99.99, -99.99
27.08, -83.03
28.41, -82.15
30.20, -81.25
30.61, -80.64
```

Just need to parse multiple instances that show up.

**UPDATE for better explanation.**

```
... CATEGORICAL ...

ENH    38298326 40108202 40518094 40357974 39907953 39017948
       38038052 36148202 35848297 35888367 36618371 38298326
SLGT   30440169 31710202 33010185 33730148 34010037 33999962
       33709892 32869871 30979883 29539912 29430025 30440169
SLGT   33548672 34408661 35918543 36858496 38648520 41018363
       41588227 41918045 41377903 40177805 38927813 37817869
       36678030 35068154 33368262 33078321 32888462 33548672
SLGT   41788755 41698893 42069059 42639132 43889124 44438960
       44438757 43988717 43278708 42398720 41788755
MRGL   29720174 31900221 33650181 34160154 34430032 34649931
       34159800 32539784 31359767 30059748 29299723 28969581
       28959440 99999999 26769674 26579796 26139874
MRGL   42897922 41907743 40147624 38837627 37637700 35897915
       35028021 34038079 33118130 31938225 30758424 30678620
       30988709 34128741 36208583 37738554 39508601 40628878
       41069099 43549479 44499512 44809478 45259379 44989263
       45109100 45718986 46478920 46758853 46738752 46398664
       44768565 44308457 43198218
TSTM   30488085 29978211 29408316 29068379 99999999 27138160
       27578139 27908100 27848061 27518032 26968006 26338005
       25698017 25338025 25088048 25058071 25238109 25578128
       25888157 26218171 26578170 26988163 27138160 99999999
       45427410 43217292 40247181 99999999 28650405 31910374
       33520340 35190229 35450147 36109944 36399709 35779395
       36769245 38319148 40189373 41219571 41299753 39959979
       38220054 37320091 36560136 36070290 36100295 35840394
       36790544 37150626 37880709 39110774 40120876 41150895
       41600769 41890540 43070599 43580863 43390914 43401262
       44171458 45521497 46131301 47181242 47561286 48251548
       48671765 49371856
```

Wanting to take this data set above and grab each available risk ENH, SLGT, MRGL, TSTM lat and long and place into this format:

```
 "Enhanced Risk"
 38.29, -83.26
 40.10, -82.02
 40.51, -80.94
 40.35, -79.74
 39.90, -79.53
 39.01, -79.48
 38.03, -80.52
 36.14, -82.02
 35.84, -82.97
 35.88, -83.67
 36.61, -83.71
 38.29, -83.26
End:


"Slight Risk"
 30.44, -101.69
 31.71, -102.02
 33.01, -101.85
 33.73, -101.48
 34.01, -100.37
 33.99, -99.62
 33.70, -98.92
 32.86, -98.71
 30.97, -98.83
 29.53, -99.12
 29.43, -100.25
 30.44, -101.69
End:


"Slight Risk"
 33.54, -86.72
 34.40, -86.61
 35.91, -85.43
 36.85, -84.96
 38.64, -85.20
 41.01, -83.63
 41.58, -82.27
 41.91, -80.45
 41.37, -79.03
 40.17, -78.05
 38.92, -78.13
 37.81, -78.69
 36.67, -80.30
 35.06, -81.54
 33.36, -82.62
 33.07, -83.21
 32.88, -84.62
 33.54, -86.72
End:


"Slight Risk"
 41.78, -87.55
 41.69, -88.93
 42.06, -90.59
 42.63, -91.32
 43.88, -91.24
 44.43, -89.60
 44.43, -87.57
 43.98, -87.17
 43.27, -87.08
 42.39, -87.20
 41.78, -87.55
End:


"Marginal Risk"
 29.72, -101.74
 31.90, -102.21
 33.65, -101.81
 34.16, -101.54
 34.43, -100.32
 34.64, -99.31
 34.15, -98.00
 32.53, -97.84
 31.35, -97.67
 30.05, -97.48
 29.29, -97.23
 28.96, -95.81
 28.95, -94.40
 26.76, -96.74
 26.57, -97.96
 26.13, -98.74
End:
```

Comment: When providing example input and output, please ensure that the output corresponds to the input.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are looking for. Do you want to reformat `32947889` as `32.94, 78.89`? That's easy, but you could have just asked that directly and it doesn't seem to have much to do with "multiple instances". Or do you want to handle different `MRGL` entries separately? Since the numbers in your output have no relationship with the sample input, it is really not clear.

Comment: What I am trying to do is parse multiple findings of SLGT and MRGL lines (including the lat/lon.  I can parse one line but have not figured out to parse multiple categories of the same findings.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.   As you see there are several SLGT and MRGL lines.   Sometimes there are none, sometimes one or multiple.    I want to find each one and parse based on the category of SLGT or MRGL

Comment: Thank you for helping me format my original question and results in a better viewable format!

Comment: Thanks for the information and advise, @EdMorton  So let me try this again

Comment: What I am trying to do is use the categorical data that has HIGH ENH SLGT MRGL and grab all the associated LAT/LON with each listed category and put into a AA.BB, -CC.DD format and output those results. Regardless if there is one SLGT or multiple SLGT for example

Comment: @wxmikey: I repeat my suggestion that you make the sample input and desired output *correspond*. I also suggest that your desired output be what you would like to see from the sample input, not just a part of it. If you don't do that, you'll have to do a much better job of communicating what your goal is and what problem(s) you are having implementing that goal. Also, if you actually have any documentation for the NOAA's text file format, it would be useful to include a link.

Comment: I understand that the input and output will be very long if you use real data. So I suggest simplifying the input data, but not in a way which hides your goal.

Comment: @rici  I have updated the input data and the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a little awk program which seems to work, although I'm not certain about some of the details. In particular, I don't know what the minimum value for longitude is; evidently, a value under the minimum has 100 added to it before the longitude is negated. So you'll have to change `LON_THRESHOLD` to what you consider the correct value.

I've tried to avoid the usual temptation to golf awk programs into a textual minimum, in the hopes that the way this program works is less obscure. But it's entirely possible that some awkisms snuck in anyway. I added a bit of explanation at the end.

```
BEGIN      { risk["HIGH"] = "High Risk"
             risk["ENH"] = "Enhanced Risk"
             risk["SLGT"] = "Slight Risk"
             risk["MRGL"] = "Marginal Risk"
             LON_THRESHOLD = 30
             END_STRING = "End:"
           }
END        { if (in_risk) print END_STRING }
in_risk && substr($0, 1, 1) != " " {
             print END_STRING "\n" "\n"
             in_risk = 0
           }
$1 in risk { printf("\"%s\"\n", risk[$1])
             in_risk = 2
           }
in_risk    { for (i = in_risk; i <= NF; ++i) {
               lat = substr($i, 1, 4) / 100
               lon = substr($i, 5, 4) / 100
               if (lon < LON_THRESHOLD) lon += 100
               printf "%5.2f, %.2f\n", lat, -lon
             }
             in_risk = 1
           }
```

Save that program as, for example, `noaa.awk`, and then apply it with:

```
awk -f noaa.awk input.txt
```

---

By way of explanation:

Awk programs consist of a series of rules. Each rule has a predicate -- that is, an expression which evaluates to a true or false value -- and an action.

Awk processes each line from its input in turn, running through all of the rules and executing the actions of the ones whose predicates evaluate to a true value. Inside the action, you can use the `$` operator to access individual fields in the input (by default, fields are separated with whitespace). `$0` is the entire input line, and `$n` is field number `n`. Unlike bash/sh, `$` is an operator and can be applied to an expression.

`BEGIN` and `END` rules are special, in that they are not real variables. `BEGIN` rules are executed exactly once, before any other processing; `END` rules are executed exactly once after all processing is finished. In this example, as is common, `BEGIN` is used to initialise reference data, while `END` is used for any necessary termination -- in this case, printing the final `End:` line.

In cases like this, where the desired action is really dependent on where we are in the file, it's necessary to build some kind of state machine, and I did that using the variable `in_risk`, which has three possible values:

- 0 or undefined: We're not currently in a block corresponding to a risk selector.
- 1: The current line, if it starts with a space, is part of a previously identified risk selector.
- 2: The current line has been detected as starting with a risk selector.

The reason for the difference between the last two values is that `$1` in a line which starts with a risk selector is the risk selector, whereas in a line which starts with a space, `$1` is actually the first number. So when we're iterating over the numbers in a line, we have to start with `$2` for lines which start with a risk selector.

Comment: Thanks!   That is just about right.  When I run it like you have in your example, I do display all of the associated lat/lon.  Only a total of 6 lat and lon from each category.  I will need all lat/lon per category.

Comment: @wxmikey: I think you tried it before I fixed the typo. Sorry about the confusion. (I had `==` instead of the correct `!=`)

Comment: That was it!  Thanks for your help.  Seeing you put the categories into an array helped make it make sense.  Was foreseeing the ultimate goal of all the categories yet writing scripts in one dimension then writing from there to go all out.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just asking how to turn a file of lines of like `AABBCCDD` into lines like `AA.BB, -CC.DD`:

```
perl -nE '/^(..)(..)(..)(..)$/ && say "$1.$2, -$3.$4"' MRGL_output.txt
```

(There's almost certainly better ways to get from your original input to those lines, but I'm not really clear on what your posted code is doing or why)

---

I *think* this will process your original input correctly, but can't be sure because the numbers in your sample output don't match up with your sample input so I can't verify:

```
perl -anE 'if (/^MRGL/ .. /^TSTM/) { exit if /^TSTM/; push @nums, @F }
           END { for (@nums) {
                   if (/^(..)(..)(..)(..)$/) { say "$1.$2, -$3.$4" }
               }}' day1_status
```

Comment: Thanks @Shawn.  Let me see if I can clarify.

What I am trying to do is look at this site for the risk of severe weather.  From High to Moderate to Enhanced to Slight risks.   There could be multiple risks of the same just in a different location.  I am trying to group the categories together and plot using the latitude and longitude provided but in the AA.BB, -CC.DD format for each individual risk area.  Very much like the image in the link:  https://www.spc.noaa.gov/products/outlook/day1otlk.html

Comment: Here is the source file to obtain the risk categories and the associated lat/lon for each risk:  https://www.spc.noaa.gov/products/outlook/archive/2019/KWNSPTSDY1_201906241300.txt

Comment: @wxmikey The problem is that the numbers in your sample input don't seem to match up in any way to the numbers in your sample output so it's not clear how you get from A to B. Plus your shell script is really... strange. It looks like you're trying to split up lines of numbers so that each number is on its own line?  But only for ones that start with MRGL until a line that starts with TSTM? Anyways, see edit.

Comment: You are correct.  This was from the other day.    Definitely not the current day. I could run it again to grab the latest to help?

Comment: Please see the ... CATEGORICAL ... text file listed at the top of this post.  I am wanting to find each category if exists and parse each one whether it be a single category or multiple category.

Answer (score 0):

Got GNU Awk?

```
awk -v RS='\\s+' '
        /[A-Z]/ {p = /^MRGL$/? 1: 0; next}
        p {print gensub(/(..)(..)(..)(..)/, "\\1.\\2, -\\3.\\4", "G")}
' file
```

- `-v RS'\\s+'` - Use any amount of whitespace as the Record Separator
- `/[A-Z]/ {...}` - On records with uppercase alphabetics, do
- `p = /^MRGL$/? 1: 0; next` - Set flag if record is MRGL, else unset, but always skip any other rules.
- `p {print gensub(...)}` - Print result of `gensub` if flag is set
- `/(...)/, "\\1", "G"` - [Capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html), Backreferences, `G`lobal substitution.